# gdb: how does it get the information of the executable?

Tags: gcc, gdb

We can set breakpoint at a func, hence gdb knows the entrance and exit address of a certain function. But how does it get this information? Does it uses DWARF or readelf for the executable, if yes, how?
**Thanks**

Comment: Depends on the architecture and the tool chain but gdb can read DWARF, STABS and other formats.

Answer (score 1):

GDB uses multiple "signals":

- It reads the symbol table.
- It may apply heuristics to skip past function prolog (usually you don't want to stop in a function prolog, as call parameters may not have yet been set up, and will look "funny" if printed).
- If
  available, it also reads debug info
  (which could be `DWARF`, `STABS`, or
  something else depending on the
  platform and the compiler).

Generally GDB will not call into "external" `readelf` executable -- it contains all the smarts to read the info directly.

If you want to know *exactly* how this is done, read the [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.2.tar.bz2).

Answer (score 0):

A function is described in DWARF with a DIE (debugging information entry) with tag `DW_TAG_subroutine`. The DIE has attributes `DW_AT_low_pc` and `DW_AT_high_pc`, which give the bounds of the function.